# SSRS textbox hanging indent

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I currently have a text box within a table that displays multiple stores based on user parameter input.  The problem that I am experiencing that I would like to have a hanging indent that will force the store name to indent once it wraps to the next line (see screenshot).
[image: Parameter label that needs a hanging indent]

Is this possible?  I am aware that I could put the "Stores:" in it's own textbox, however this makes it difficult when it comes to lining up report items to prevent hidden/merged cells/columns during export to Excel.

The code that I am currently using in the text box is `="<b>" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.iif(Parameters!StoreKey.Count > 1, "Stores:  ", "Store:  ") & "</b>" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Join(Parameters!StoreKey.Label, ", ")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Textbox property you're looking for is called `HangingIndent`. Try setting it to -10pt.

[image]

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks so much, I had messed around with that property before but I had been using positive numbers and I didn't see a change.  I thought it weird to have the property if it didn't do anything.  Will note that for the future.  Here I thought I would need some crazy expression

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table, in the first column you put "Stores: ", in the second the string value, set the borders to none and finally play a little with the alignment (First column top-right alignment & Second column top-left alignment, its your choice) to make it look as if it was all in a single text box.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This was the original layout that I had in place, however I needed to combine the label and the parameters into one text box.  My reasoning was because the Export to Excel feature was so lousy that because the tiny Stores: text box would have to line up with a larger text box below (report table), it really effected the way in which Stores was presented.  i.e. right-aligned which made it far away from the edge of the report, if that makes any sense.